# greater than but less than function in python usage

Tags: python

while I was studding python I run into this problem that I'm trying to filter if a number is bigger than n and smaller than x
in other thread I read that you could just do this:
if 10 < a < 20:
    whatever
but when  I run the code Im getting invalid syntax

```
while guess != rightnum:

    guess=int(input('your guess: '))
    diff= abs(guess - rightnum)

    if guess > rightnum and diff >= 1000 :
        print(random.choice(muchless))
    elif guess > rightnum and 1000 > diff >= 100
        print(random.choice(less))
    elif guess > rightnum and diff < 100
        print(random.choice(fewless))
```

Comment: You forgot the colons `:` at the end of your `elif` statements.

Comment: thats it. thank you kindly

Answer (score 1):

your elif statements don't end with `:`!

Answer (score 0):

You missed 2 colons

```
while guess != rightnum:

    guess=int(input('your guess: '))
    diff= abs(guess - rightnum)

    if guess > rightnum and diff >= 1000 :
        print(random.choice(muchless))
    elif guess > rightnum and 1000 > diff >= 100 :
        print(random.choice(less))
    elif guess > rightnum and diff < 100 :
        print(random.choice(fewless))
```